# Generic dictionnary with enum keys

Tags: typescript

I can't get [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngaWHAzlA3gKClAYgeXygF4oByA-MgGmygCEBBAJRPKeZswF9NMAXOAAdgsOABEAlgGN%20kgPYgQAQwBOcNlhw4A2kNXyhUSSDFJUAXQBcUFP1UmA5jz7TFdqABMZcxSvVW8FKyCkpqGqRa2jrw5igAdJTWZAAWwAA26fJc2lAxiMgJHNbkAO7yqumeZC58giJQAOKgwA7Swb5h6gA8jCBwAKLgEAB8mnS6%20obGpn2DwyV2DiDOvAD0AFQb2BtQACrComRzQ5Bkxmgg8vxQyigoko4qAEbpovzyUPVHS05QAD5QYbPVoA2xwCDPeTpMjxOgHBrHfqnCDnSSXa63e6PF5vL6fb7kFAQqEwnZrIA) to work

```
enum MyKeys {
  FOO = 'FOO',
  BAR = 'BAR',
}

type MyDictionnary = {
    [prop in MyKeys]: string
}

const dictionnary: MyDictionnary = {
    [MyKeys.FOO]:'hello',
    [MyKeys.BAR]: 'world'
}


type GenericDictionnary<AnyEnum> = {
    [prop in AnyEnum]: string
}
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
Type 'AnyEnum' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
  Type 'AnyEnum' is not assignable to type 'symbol'
```

What am I missing out on ?

Comment: Keys can only be strings, numbers or symbols.

Comment: You can add that specific constraint to your generic with `type GenericDictionnary<AnyEnum extends string | number | symbol>`. That way, TS knows that AnyEnum will have a valid key type

Comment: Or `AnyEnum extends PropertyKey`, but of course it won't limit it to `enums` only

Comment: And you already have such helper [builtin](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) `Record<MyKeys, string>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accept only `enum` you should use `string | number` constraint. Because only `string` and `number` are acceptable values for `enums`.

```js
enum MyKeys {
  FOO = 'FOO',
  BAR = 'BAR',
}

type MyDictionnary = {
  [prop in MyKeys]: string
}

const dictionnary: MyDictionnary = {
  [MyKeys.FOO]: 'hello',
  [MyKeys.BAR]: 'world'
}


type GenericDictionnary<AnyEnum extends number | string> = {
  [prop in AnyEnum]: string
}

// type Result = {
//     FOO: string;
//     BAR: string;
// }
type Result = GenericDictionnary<MyKeys>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngaWHAzlA3gKClAYgeXygF4oByA-MgGmygCEBBAJRPKeZswF9NMAXOAAdgsOABEAlgGN%20kgPYgQAQwBOcNlhwBtIavlCokkGKSoAugC4oKfquMBzHn2mLbUACYy5ileuvwUrIKSmoapFpQ2vBmKAB0lFbkABbAADZp8lw6McjxHElkAO7yqmkeZM58giJQAOKgwPbSQT6h6gA8jCBwAKLg0MAAHvygHmgDAEZNUAA%20NnaOAHyadLr6hsZQ3X0DSbb2IE68mAD0p1A1oszAKGBp-KvnOC%20U1geOANxnFy8MLO9Fkdvs9eFcoDc7g82A0QE0ZK0Qn44B1cqglkA)